librería "prob", problemas de instalación
No puedo instalar la librería "prob" en la versión de R 4.1.2, me sale este mensaje:

library(prob) Error in library(prob) : there is no package called
‘prob’

Pero esa librería existe en otras versiones de R. Es para simular muestras aleatorias, entre otras cosas.
Muchas gracias

Ni idea de R, pero parece un problema general en que el paquete ha sido retirado. Mira esta respuesta, en inglés.

¡Hola!
Tal y como apunta @aeportugal, el paquete ha sido eliminado del CRAN y por tanto no lo podrás instalar directamente.
No obstante, tienes la opción de hacerlo manualmente a través de los archivos que te indican que están disponibles  [Enlace]
Saludos,
